# Onsen Carousel Vertical Scroll

Tags: jquery, mobile, carousel, onsen-ui

I am working on a mobile app using Onsen UI Framework, and wanted the ability to swipe between pages or content.  I added the carousel and placed pages in the div, and it worked for the most part.  The only issue remaining is I cannot scroll the content vertically to see all the writing.

How to fix this?

Comment: What have you tried so far. It may help to answer if you can show a (minimal) example of what you are using now

Comment: Here is what I'm working off of:  http://codepen.io/adan/pen/ByorbY

Where the colors are named, I simply place a <ons-page> content and it shows it, but no ability to scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ons-scroller` tag.

You have to set the `height` attribute in `ons-scroller` tag which will make the content vertically scrollable, for example;

```
<ons-scroller style="height: 800px; width: 100%">
    <ons-carousel style="width: 100%; height: 200px">
        <ons-carousel-item>
        </ons-carousel-item>
        <ons-carousel-item>
        </ons-carousel-item>
    </ons-carousel>
</ons-scroller>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use direction="vertical".

```
<ons-carousel direction="vertical">
...
</ons-carousel>
```